# run multiple commands in docker after container start

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, docker, shell

how can I run /bin/run1.sh and /bin/run2.sh after the container startup!
also, if you can tell me how can I send the logs of /bin/run1.sh and /bin/run2.sh to container logs!!

**Docker file**

```
FROM ruby:2.5
COPY run1.sh /bin
COPY run2.sh /bin
RUN chmod +x /bin/run1.sh
RUN chmod +x /bin/run2.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid
# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

**run1.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date` $@ >> /log.txt;
cat log.txt;
```

**run2.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date` $@ >> /log2.txt;
cat log.txt;
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve by this? do you want to access the ruby logs of your app?

Comment: thanks for your reply Mshka!
just I wanna run some scripts for database migration after the container starts. plus if it is possible to send their logs to the container so we can monitor the progress of the database migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]` to `ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh", "run1.sh", "run2.sh"]` which will run your custom bash scripts

you also need to create the `log.txt` file if it does not exist and to add `exec "$@"` to resume the container's main process

so your `runX.sh` files should look like this

```sh
#!/bin/sh
touch log.txt;
echo `date` $@ >> log.txt;
cat log.txt;
exec "$@"
```

note that if you are running DB migration on rails they should be logged in your application log which can be accessed through the docker container itself (get the docker id from `docker ps` then access the bash `docker exec -it /bin/bash` where you can navigate to `/logs/{your environment}.log`)

Comment: here what I had to edit with following your instruction

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh", "run1.sh", "run2.sh"]

after building the container, it starts then exit 


""""Error response from daemon: Container f7f77ef11dcf53db4c375d00c696d07a607543b823610592a0f7a375eeafcc26 is not running"""""

Comment: I had to update the run.sh files to resume containers command, updated answer

Comment: thanks, Mashka for your advice!
after I did what you said. unfortunately, the container run the script before it starts rails server as it mentioned in CMD

  CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

Comment: Exit Code 127
Command ["bundle exec bin/rake db:migrate"]

Comment: yes these scripts will run before the CMD command to launch the server, 127 error means it did not find the command where are you trying to run this?

Comment: so, how we make sure that our scripts ( run1, run2 )  will run after the main service starts Mshka!

Comment: @AbdallaKenawy not really sure i've never done this before: have you tried moving the `ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh", "run1.sh", "run2.sh"]` after the CMD command - another approach would be to use docker-compose.yml and create a command dependant on the rails server